Ways to install packages in miniconda CL
I know you can use conda install r-[name], but I've seen other people using Rscript -e install.packages(), though I've not had much luck with this method personally.  I've also seen BiocManager::install.packages() used.
I've mostly used the first method listed, but I'm curious as to what the benefits of using other methods are, and haven't been able to find any consistent answer online so far.  What are the different ways to install packages using miniconda CL? Are there pros/cons to the various methods, or more of just a personal preference?
